# If statement in jQuery and HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I m running the following script with success : it updates the text every 3s

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  window.setInterval(function() {
    loadNewText()
  }, 3000)

  function loadNewText() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/update_report",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $(report).replaceWith(data)
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

I want to change the function in HTML to run 'loadNewText()' only if there's changes in certain variable in Python code !

I've put the variables in python route :

```
@app.route('/console-output')
def console_output():
    fileHandle = open("console_output.txt", "r")
    lineList = fileHandle.readlines()
    fileHandle.close()
    last= lineList[len(lineList)-1]
    with open('console_output.txt', 'r') as r:
        co =r.read()
    return render_template("console-output.html",console_output_msg=console_output_msg, last=last, co=co)
```

and write the following code in HTML :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

  if (last != console_output_msg) {
    loadNewText();
  }

  function loadNewText() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/update_text",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $(new_text).replaceWith(data)
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

**This method is not working** ! I don't have a big experience with Javascript! I don't know if I m not calling the variables (last, console_output_msg) the right way or my function is not valide !

If there's any way to correct it or any other suggestion to call 'loadNewText()' when changes happens in python code !

Thanks!

Comment: You can't access server variables in the client. And you've gotten rid of the `setInterval`, so it doesn't run repeatedly.

Comment: What you want is logically impossible. The Python code doesn't run until you make the AJAX call. So the variable doesn't get a value until you call it, and only then can you test if it has changed from the previous call.

Comment: @Barmar is it possible to use `setInterval` to compare the two variables coming from the Python code and run the function under certain condition ?

Comment: You need to make an AJAX call to get the variable from Python into JS.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please give an example or a link where I can find more about that solution ?

Comment: You could have two routes: one to ask if anything has changed, and a second one to get the updated text.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea where you would find something like that at a link. Just think about it logically and write the code.

Comment: You're supposed to be a programmer, not a copy-paster.

Comment: @Barmar Like I've mentioned in my post I'm not experienced with Javascript ! I've asked for an example to understand your suggestion not to copy-paste! Thanks for your help I'll try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can't access server variables on the client.

You could save the previous output in a JavaScript variable, and only update the DOM if it has changed. You need to put the `if` statement inside the `loadNewText()` function, after it has received the response, so it can compare it.

This won't skip the AJAX call, but it will avoid refreshing the page when nothing has changed.

```js
$(function() {
  let last_output;
  window.setInterval(loadNewText, 3000)

  function loadNewText() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/update_report",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        if (data != last_output) {
          $(report).replaceWith(data);
          last_output = data;
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining but my problem is that I want to avoid calling the function every 3s! I mean avoid accessing the update_report route every 3s ! I m looking for a solution to only update when changes happens in a certain textfile that is my input in Python! Thanks

Comment: You have to call to the server, the client has no way of knowing if the file on the server has changed.

Comment: Here's an analogy: You only want to call your mother if she's sick. But you can't find out if she's sick without calling and asking her.

Comment: Okey! Thanks for your patience ! I will look for more informations about it!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 popular ways to update the text when there is a change in Python:

- **Long polling**
  Using `setInterval()` function to trigger an ajax call to the server to check if there are any changes.
- **WebSocket**
  Implement a WebSocket connection between the server and browser. Receive the message sent from the server.

  Link for implement WebSocket in Python.
  https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/8.1/intro.html

Comment: He's asking how to implement long polling, he just didn't call it that.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I guess it is the simplest way in his case. Because he wants to eliminate the call `loadNewText()` function, I let him know there is another option in case he doesn't know that.